# How to stop an Azure Event Hub Consumer Client in Python

Tags: python, async-await, azure-eventhub

I am running into some trouble with Azure Event Bub with Python. Below is my strater code for connection (Taken from microsoft docs)

```
import asyncio
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import BlobCheckpointStore


async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    # Print the event data.
    print("Received the event: \"{}\" from the partition with ID: \"{}\"".format(event.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8'), partition_context.partition_id))

    # Update the checkpoint so that the program doesn't read the events
    # that it has already read when you run it next time.
    await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)

async def main():
    # Create an Azure blob checkpoint store to store the checkpoints.
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string("AZURE STORAGE CONNECTION STRING", "BLOB CONTAINER NAME")

    # Create a consumer client for the event hub.
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string("EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING", consumer_group="$Default", eventhub_name="EVENT HUB NAME", checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store)
    async with client:
        # Call the receive method. Read from the beginning of the partition (starting_position: "-1")
        await client.receive(on_event=on_event,  starting_position="-1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # Run the main method.
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Here, the receiver/consumer keeps listening. If I remove any of the awaits the consumer throws an error.
Does anyone know how to stop the consumer after running for some time like timeout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Abhishek

There are 2 options here :

1. You could stop listening when there is an inactivity for certain period time.
2. You could stop listening after fixed duration.

Have detailed both in below steps.

### **OPTION 1**

You could use the max_wait_time parameter in order to stop listening in case there is no activity for certain time.

[image]

I did spin up a simple use case of the above. But you could optimize this further.

```
import asyncio
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient

event_hub_connection_str = '<CON_STR>'
eventhub_name = '<EventHub_NAME>'


consumer = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
     conn_str=event_hub_connection_str,
       consumer_group='$Default',
       eventhub_name=eventhub_name  # EventHub name should be specified if it doesn't show up in connection string.
   )

#this event gets called when the message is received or Max_Wait_time is clocked
async def on_event(partition_context, event):
       print(event) #Optional - to see output
       #Checks whether there is any event returned None. None is returned when this event is called after the Max_Wait_time is crossed
       if(event !=None):
            print("Received the event: \"{}\" from the partition with ID: \"{}\"".format(event.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8'), partition_context.partition_id))
            #you can update other code like updating blob store
                
       else:
           print("Timeout is Hit")
           #updating the 
           global receive
           receive = False

  
async def close():
    print("Closing the client.")
    await consumer.close()
    print("Closed")
    
async def main():
    recv_task = asyncio.ensure_future(consumer.receive(on_event=on_event,max_wait_time=15))
    while(True): # keep receiving for 3 seconds
        await asyncio.sleep(3) 
        if(receive != True):
            print("Cancelling the Task")
            recv_task.cancel()  # stop receiving by cancelling the task
            break;
  
   

receive = True
asyncio.run(main())
asyncio.run(close())#closing the Client
```

With regards to the above code. If there is no activity 15 seconds the async task gets cancelled and the consumer clients gets closed. The program is eventually exited gracefully.

### **OPTION 2**

If you are looking for a code in which the you would like to make client to listen for fixed time like 1 hour or some thing. You could refer the below code

[Reference Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.aio.eventhubconsumerclient?view=azure-python#close------none)

```
event_hub_connection_str = '<>'
eventhub_name = '<>'
import asyncio

from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient

consumer = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
       conn_str=event_hub_connection_str,
       consumer_group='$Default',
       eventhub_name=eventhub_name  # EventHub name should be specified if it doesn't show up in connection string.
   )
async def on_event(partition_context, event):
       # Put your code here.
       # If the operation is i/o intensive, async will have better performance.
       print("Received event from partition: {}".format(partition_context.partition_id))

   # The receive method is a coroutine which will be blocking when awaited.
   # It can be executed in an async task for non-blocking behavior, and combined with the 'close' method.
   
async def main():
        recv_task = asyncio.ensure_future(consumer.receive(on_event=on_event))
        await asyncio.sleep(15)  # keep receiving for 3 seconds
        recv_task.cancel()  # stop receiving

async def close():
    print("Closing.....")
    await consumer.close()
    print("Closed") 

asyncio.run(main())
asyncio.run(close())#closing the Client
```

The below code that is responsible for the client to be listening for a certain time :

```
recv_task =
asyncio.ensure_future(consumer.receive(on_event=on_event))    
await asyncio.sleep(3)  # keep receiving for 3 seconds    
recv_task.cancel()
```

You could increase the time as per your need.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. This looks good. Though I did not try this I solved my problem in a very similar way.

Comment: @abhishek-sunkara Is there any way how to stop it without using asyncio?

Answer (score 0):

@Satya V   I tried the option 2  but however I am seeing the error ,

There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.

But However your code helped me in a better way . I had configured the code with Storage Account check point

```
import asyncio
import os
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import BlobCheckpointStore

CONNECTION_STR = ''
EVENTHUB_NAME = ''
STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR = ''
BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME = ""


async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    
    print("Received event from partition: {}.".format(partition_context.partition_id))
    await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)


async def receive(client):
   
    await client.receive(
        on_event=on_event,
        starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
    )
    
async def main():
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR, BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        CONNECTION_STR,
        consumer_group="$Default",
        eventhub_name=EVENTHUB_NAME,
        checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store,  # For load-balancing and checkpoint. Leave None for no load-balancing.
    )
    async with client:
        recv_task = asyncio.ensure_future(receive(client))
        await asyncio.sleep(4)  # keep receiving for 3 seconds
        recv_task.cancel()  # stop receiving
        await client.close()

async def close():
    print("Closing.....")
    print("Closed")         

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    asyncio.run(close())#closing the Client
```